# Simple to implement struct for memory efficient list of tuples

Tags: python, memory

I need to create a list of the following type

```
[(latitude, longitude, date), ...]
```

where latitude and longitude are floats, and date is an integer.  I'm running out of memory on my local machine because I need to store about 60 million of these tuples.  What is the most memory efficient (and at the same time simple to implement) way of representing these tuples in python?

The precision of the latitude and longitude does not need to be so great (just enough to represent values such as -65.100234) and the integers need to be big enough to handle UNIX timestamps.

I have used swig before to define "c-structs" which are in general much more memory efficient than they python, but this is complicated to implement...maybe there some scipy or numpy way to declare such tuples that uses less memory...any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need all this information in memory? Is storing on disk not an option?

Comment: I can indeed store it to disk.  In fact, I'm loading it out of a sqlite database.  The operations that I want to perform later are much quicker if all the data is in memory because I don't have to perform so many DB transactions.    And eumiro, yes, you're right I need 32-bit ints for unix timestamps, I've updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: `sqlite` is a slow database. It is only suited for small databases. Yours is a huge one and in this case you should be using `mysql`. `sqlite` has performance issues when the database size is very huge but `mysql` just does not budge not matter how large the database is. So, in my opinion switch to `mysql`. Anyways, if you are doing some real programming, you will have to sooner or later switch to `mysql`.

Comment: You could use something like protocol buffers or even the standard 'struct' module to encode them to bytes, but then you have a performance hit decoding each one as you want to use it. Perhaps you could use Cython, and translate the functions that handle the data directly into C, so that the data can be stored as a C array.

Comment: Guanidene:  that's a common misconception.  Especially for read only operations, SQLite is faster than mysql.  Check out this link: http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html
...but they do mention that their comparisons were done on a small db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with using NumPy, you could use a [`numpy.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html).  If you want 8 significant digits for your coordinates, single precision floats are probably just not enough, so your records would have two double precision floats and a 32-bit integer, which is twenty bytes in total, so 60 million records would need 1.2 GB of memory.  Note that NumPy arrays have fixed size and need to be reallocated if the size changes.

Code example:

```
# Create an uninitialised array with 100 records
a = numpy.recarray(100,
                   formats=["f8", "f8", "i4"],
                   names=["latitude", "longitude", "date"])
# initialise to 0
a[:] = (0.0, 0.0, 0)
# assign a single record
a[0] = (-65.100234, -38.32432, 1309351408)
# access the date of the first record
a[0].date
# access the whole date column
a.date
```

If you want to avoid a dependency on NumPy, you could also use `ctypes` arrays of `ctypes` structures, which are less convenient than NumPy arrays, but more convenient than using SWIG.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was loooking for.  Could you complete your answer with a small bit of code which shows how to use numpy.recarray to create the list that I want?  Then I'll accept your answer.